# Simplistic flash card web-app

Tags: javascript, html, quiz

**Feedback I would love to hear:** Since this is really my first real JavaScript app, being that I can never find a project I want to actually work on, I want to know how I can improve my JS techniques. Am I doing a good job separating logic? Am I using good techniques? Should I completely forget about vanilla JS and just go straight into using Jquery or other libraries? Is it good that I used the card manager as a literal? Anything and everything! I'd even appreciate some feedback on how I setup the html or if you would set it up a different way!

Any how, this is a snippet of what I have written so far, and you can find the source at https://ide.c9.io/lemony_andrew/flashcardapp
Here's the working demonstration: https://flashcardapp-lemony-andrew.c9.io/flashcard.html

```html
<body>

    <div id="newCards" >
        <center>
            Front:<input type="text" id="newFront" name="front"/>
            Back: <input type="text" id="newBack" name="back"/>
            <input value="Add" type="button" onclick="userEnter();"/>
        </center>
    </div>

    <center><h1>French Demonstration</h1></center>

    <div id="cardButton" ><p id="cardText"></p></div>

    <p align="center">
        <input type="button" id="prevCard" value="previous" onclick="cardsHandle.cardMove(-1);"/>
        <span id="positionIndex">0/0</span>
        <input type="button" id="nextCard" value="next" onclick="cardsHandle.cardMove(1);"/>
    </p>

    <script> 
        String.prototype.isEmpty = function() {// Returns if a string has only whitespace
            return (this.length === 0 || !this.trim());
        };

        function Card(front, back){
            /*A card is just a container that holds a front and back value! 
                - You can get either back or front by displaying it*/
            this.frontVal = front;
            this.backVal = back;

            this.display = function(side){
                if( side === 0 ){
                    return this.frontVal;
                }else{
                    return this.backVal;
                }
            };
        }

        var cardsHandle = {
            cards: [],
            cardInd: 0,
            cardButton: document.getElementById("cardButton"),
            cardText: document.getElementById("cardText"),
            cardTPosition: document.getElementById("positionIndex"),
            cardSide: 0,

            cardAdd: function(back, front){
                this.cards.push( new Card(back, front) );
            },
            cardUpdate: function(){
                var curCard = this.cards[ this.cardInd ];
                this.cardText.innerHTML = curCard.display( this.cardSide );
                this.cardTPosition.innerHTML = (this.cardInd+1)+"/"+this.cards.length;
            },
            cardFlip: function(){
                this.cardSide = (this.cardSide + 1) % 2;
            },
            cardMove: function(moveBy){
                this.cardInd += moveBy;
                if( this. cardInd < 0 ){
                    this.cardInd += this.cards.length;
                }
                this.cardInd = this.cardInd % this.cards.length;

                this.cardSide = 0;// Set back to front
                this.cardUpdate();
            },
            cardTap: function(){
                this.cardFlip();
                this.cardUpdate();// Display card
            }
        };

        cardsHandle.cardAdd("Hello or Good bye","Salut");
        cardsHandle.cardAdd("Hello or Good Morning","Bonjour");
        cardsHandle.cardAdd("Good Night","Bonne nuit!");
        cardsHandle.cardUpdate();

        var userEnter = function(){
            var nFront = document.getElementById("newFront"),
                nBack = document.getElementById("newBack");

            if( nFront.value.isEmpty() || nBack.value.isEmpty() )
                return;

            cardsHandle.cardAdd(nFront.value,nBack.value);
            nFront.value="";
            nBack.value="";
            cardsHandle.cardUpdate();
        }

        cardsHandle.cardButton.addEventListener('click', function(){ cardsHandle.cardTap();} );

    </script>

</body>
```

**Program Overview:**
Basically I have 3 functions to my program. The container that just holds and displays the front and back values of a card. The second functionality is basically the card handler. It's purpose is basically to manage what is put on the screen, and how the index of cards is sorted/manipulated. The third functionality is simply having the user be able to add in cards.

**Why I'm making this:** I'm working on making a *completely free and completely open-source* flash-card web-app. The reason I'm making it is because I find that most flash card apps are not simple enough (*just not enjoyable to work with*), don't have a good folder (organizing) system, and are just not free. This is just the beginning of my application, and it will essentially be my first real JavaScript work. I don't normally use JavaScript, in fact it's been nearly 4 months since I touched it, so this is a good refresher for me and will hopefully be a part of my future portfolio. (I also hope it will be my foot in the door for bigger contributor communities like Github).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTML:

- Don’t use the `center` element or the `align` attribute. Both are [obsolete](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-html5-20141028/obsolete.html#non-conforming-features) in HTML5. Use CSS instead (e.g., `text-align:center;`).
- Use [`label`](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-html5-20141028/forms.html#the-label-element) elements for your form fields (except for the submit buttons), e.g.:

  ```html
  <label for="newFront">Front:</label> <input type="text" id="newFront" name="newFront">
  ```
- You could (i.e., it’s not required) use a [`fieldset`](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-html5-20141028/forms.html#the-fieldset-element) to group the elements of the form for creating new flashcards, and give them a name (e.g., "Create new flashard").
- You could use [`article`](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-html5-20141028/sections.html#the-article-element) for each flashcard.

Accessibility:

- Currently it doesn’t seem possible to use this web app with keyboard only. While you can create new flashards and navigate existing cards, you can’t reveal the back of a card. Possible solution: Add a "Flip" (or similar) button.